# Detekt: Autocorrect feature is not working

Tags: android, gradle, detekt

I have included detekt (https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt/) in my project:

**root build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    ext.detekt_version = "1.0.1"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-gradle-plugin:$detekt_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt").version("1.0.1")
}
```

**app build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt'
```

android {
        // .. just defaults
    }

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    // ... other dependencies

    detekt "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-formatting:$detekt_version"
    detekt("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-cli:$detekt_version")

}

detekt {
    toolVersion = "$detekt_version"
    input = files("src/main/java")
    filters = ".*/resources/.*,.*/build/.*"
    config = files("../detekt/detekt-config.yml")
    reports {
        xml {
            enabled = true
        }
        html {
            enabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

The rules file **../detekt/detekt-config.yml**

```
autoCorrect: true

test-pattern: # Configure exclusions for test sources
  active: true
  patterns: # Test file regexes
  - '.*/test/.*'
  - '.*/androidTest/.*'
  - '.*Test.kt'
  - '.*Spec.kt'
  - '.*Spek.kt'
  exclude-rule-sets:
  - 'comments'
  exclude-rules:
  - 'NamingRules'
  - 'WildcardImport'
  - 'MagicNumber'
  - 'MaxLineLength'
  - 'LateinitUsage'
  - 'StringLiteralDuplication'
  - 'SpreadOperator'
  - 'TooManyFunctions'
  - 'ForEachOnRange'
  - 'FunctionMaxLength'
  - 'TooGenericExceptionCaught'
  - 'InstanceOfCheckForException'

build:
  maxIssues: 100
  weights:
  # complexity: 2
  # LongParameterList: 1
  # style: 1
  # comments: 1

processors:
  active: true
  exclude:
  # - 'FunctionCountProcessor'
  # - 'PropertyCountProcessor'
  # - 'ClassCountProcessor'
  # - 'PackageCountProcessor'
  # - 'KtFileCountProcessor'

console-reports:
  active: true
  exclude:
  #  - 'ProjectStatisticsReport'
  #  - 'ComplexityReport'
  #  - 'NotificationReport'
  #  - 'FindingsReport'
  #  - 'BuildFailureReport'

comments:
  active: true
  CommentOverPrivateFunction:
    active: false
  CommentOverPrivateProperty:
    active: false
  EndOfSentenceFormat:
    active: false
    endOfSentenceFormat: ([.?!][ \t\n\r\f<])|([.?!]$)
  UndocumentedPublicClass:
    active: false
    searchInNestedClass: true
    searchInInnerClass: true
    searchInInnerObject: true
    searchInInnerInterface: true
  UndocumentedPublicFunction:
    active: false

complexity:
  active: true
  ComplexCondition:
    active: true
    threshold: 4
  ComplexInterface:
    active: false
    threshold: 10
    includeStaticDeclarations: false
  ComplexMethod:
    active: true
    threshold: 10
    ignoreSingleWhenExpression: false
    ignoreSimpleWhenEntries: false
  LabeledExpression:
    active: false
    ignoredLabels: ""
  LargeClass:
    active: true
    threshold: 600
  LongMethod:
    active: true
    threshold: 60
  LongParameterList:
    active: true
    threshold: 6
    ignoreDefaultParameters: false
  MethodOverloading:
    active: false
    threshold: 6
  NestedBlockDepth:
    active: true
    threshold: 4
  StringLiteralDuplication:
    active: false
    threshold: 3
    ignoreAnnotation: true
    excludeStringsWithLessThan5Characters: true
    ignoreStringsRegex: '$^'
  TooManyFunctions:
    active: true
    thresholdInFiles: 11
    thresholdInClasses: 11
    thresholdInInterfaces: 11
    thresholdInObjects: 11
    thresholdInEnums: 11
    ignoreDeprecated: false
    ignorePrivate: false
    ignoreOverridden: false

empty-blocks:
  active: true
  EmptyCatchBlock:
    active: true
    allowedExceptionNameRegex: "^(_|(ignore|expected).*)"
  EmptyClassBlock:
    active: true
  EmptyDefaultConstructor:
    active: true
  EmptyDoWhileBlock:
    active: true
  EmptyElseBlock:
    active: true
  EmptyFinallyBlock:
    active: true
  EmptyForBlock:
    active: true
  EmptyFunctionBlock:
    active: true
    ignoreOverriddenFunctions: false
  EmptyIfBlock:
    active: true
  EmptyInitBlock:
    active: true
  EmptyKtFile:
    active: true
  EmptySecondaryConstructor:
    active: true
  EmptyWhenBlock:
    active: true
  EmptyWhileBlock:
    active: true

exceptions:
  active: true
  ExceptionRaisedInUnexpectedLocation:
    active: false
    methodNames: 'toString,hashCode,equals,finalize'
  InstanceOfCheckForException:
    active: false
  NotImplementedDeclaration:
    active: false
  PrintStackTrace:
    active: false
  RethrowCaughtException:
    active: false
  ReturnFromFinally:
    active: false
  SwallowedException:
    active: false
    ignoredExceptionTypes: 'InterruptedException,NumberFormatException,ParseException,MalformedURLException'
  ThrowingExceptionFromFinally:
    active: false
  ThrowingExceptionInMain:
    active: false
  ThrowingExceptionsWithoutMessageOrCause:
    active: false
    exceptions: 'IllegalArgumentException,IllegalStateException,IOException'
  ThrowingNewInstanceOfSameException:
    active: false
  TooGenericExceptionCaught:
    active: true
    exceptionNames:
    - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    - Error
    - Exception
    - IllegalMonitorStateException
    - NullPointerException
    - IndexOutOfBoundsException
    - RuntimeException
    - Throwable
    allowedExceptionNameRegex: "^(_|(ignore|expected).*)"
  TooGenericExceptionThrown:
    active: true
    exceptionNames:
    - Error
    - Exception
    - Throwable
    - RuntimeException

formatting:
  active: true
  android: false
  autoCorrect: true
  ChainWrapping:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  CommentSpacing:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  Filename:
    active: true
  FinalNewline:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  ImportOrdering:
    active: false
  Indentation:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
    indentSize: 4
    continuationIndentSize: 4
  MaximumLineLength:
    active: true
    maxLineLength: 120
  ModifierOrdering:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  NoBlankLineBeforeRbrace:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  NoConsecutiveBlankLines:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  NoEmptyClassBody:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  NoItParamInMultilineLambda:
    active: false
  NoLineBreakAfterElse:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  NoLineBreakBeforeAssignment:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  NoMultipleSpaces:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  NoSemicolons:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  NoTrailingSpaces:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  NoUnitReturn:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  NoUnusedImports:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  NoWildcardImports:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  PackageName:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  ParameterListWrapping:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
    indentSize: 4
  SpacingAroundColon:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  SpacingAroundComma:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  SpacingAroundCurly:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  SpacingAroundKeyword:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  SpacingAroundOperators:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  SpacingAroundParens:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  SpacingAroundRangeOperator:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true
  StringTemplate:
    active: true
    autoCorrect: true

naming:
  active: true
  ClassNaming:
    active: true
    classPattern: '[A-Z$][a-zA-Z0-9$]*'
  ConstructorParameterNaming:
    active: true
    parameterPattern: '[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*'
    privateParameterPattern: '[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*'
    excludeClassPattern: '$^'
  EnumNaming:
    active: true
    enumEntryPattern: '^[A-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*'
  ForbiddenClassName:
    active: false
    forbiddenName: ''
  FunctionMaxLength:
    active: false
    maximumFunctionNameLength: 30
  FunctionMinLength:
    active: false
    minimumFunctionNameLength: 3
  FunctionNaming:
    active: true
    functionPattern: '^([a-z$][a-zA-Z$0-9]*)|(`.*`)$'
    excludeClassPattern: '$^'
    ignoreOverridden: true
  FunctionParameterNaming:
    active: true
    parameterPattern: '[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*'
    excludeClassPattern: '$^'
    ignoreOverriddenFunctions: true
  MatchingDeclarationName:
    active: true
  MemberNameEqualsClassName:
    active: false
    ignoreOverriddenFunction: true
  ObjectPropertyNaming:
    active: true
    constantPattern: '[A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*'
    propertyPattern: '[A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*'
    privatePropertyPattern: '(_)?[A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*'
  PackageNaming:
    active: true
    packagePattern: '^[a-z]+(\.[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)*$'
  TopLevelPropertyNaming:
    active: true
    constantPattern: '[A-Z][_A-Z0-9]*'
    propertyPattern: '[A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*'
    privatePropertyPattern: '(_)?[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*'
  VariableMaxLength:
    active: false
    maximumVariableNameLength: 64
  VariableMinLength:
    active: false
    minimumVariableNameLength: 1
  VariableNaming:
    active: true
    variablePattern: '[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*'
    privateVariablePattern: '(_)?[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*'
    excludeClassPattern: '$^'
    ignoreOverridden: true

performance:
  active: true
  ArrayPrimitive:
    active: false
  ForEachOnRange:
    active: true
  SpreadOperator:
    active: true
  UnnecessaryTemporaryInstantiation:
    active: true

potential-bugs:
  active: true
  DuplicateCaseInWhenExpression:
    active: true
  EqualsAlwaysReturnsTrueOrFalse:
    active: false
  EqualsWithHashCodeExist:
    active: true
  ExplicitGarbageCollectionCall:
    active: true
  InvalidRange:
    active: false
  IteratorHasNextCallsNextMethod:
    active: false
  IteratorNotThrowingNoSuchElementException:
    active: false
  LateinitUsage:
    active: false
    excludeAnnotatedProperties: ""
    ignoreOnClassesPattern: ""
  UnconditionalJumpStatementInLoop:
    active: false
  UnreachableCode:
    active: true
  UnsafeCallOnNullableType:
    active: false
  UnsafeCast:
    active: false
  UselessPostfixExpression:
    active: false
  WrongEqualsTypeParameter:
    active: false

style:
  active: true
  CollapsibleIfStatements:
    active: false
  DataClassContainsFunctions:
    active: false
    conversionFunctionPrefix: 'to'
  EqualsNullCall:
    active: false
  EqualsOnSignatureLine:
    active: false
  ExplicitItLambdaParameter:
    active: false
  ExpressionBodySyntax:
    active: false
    includeLineWrapping: false
  ForbiddenComment:
    active: true
    values: 'TODO:,FIXME:,STOPSHIP:'
  ForbiddenImport:
    active: false
    imports: ''
  ForbiddenVoid:
    active: false
  FunctionOnlyReturningConstant:
    active: false
    ignoreOverridableFunction: true
    excludedFunctions: 'describeContents'
  LoopWithTooManyJumpStatements:
    active: false
    maxJumpCount: 1
  MagicNumber:
    active: true
    ignoreNumbers: '-1,0,1,2'
    ignoreHashCodeFunction: true
    ignorePropertyDeclaration: false
    ignoreConstantDeclaration: true
    ignoreCompanionObjectPropertyDeclaration: true
    ignoreAnnotation: false
    ignoreNamedArgument: true
    ignoreEnums: false
  MandatoryBracesIfStatements:
    active: false
  MaxLineLength:
    active: true
    maxLineLength: 120
    excludePackageStatements: true
    excludeImportStatements: true
    excludeCommentStatements: false
  MayBeConst:
    active: false
  ModifierOrder:
    active: true
  NestedClassesVisibility:
    active: false
  NewLineAtEndOfFile:
    active: true
  NoTabs:
    active: false
  OptionalAbstractKeyword:
    active: true
  OptionalUnit:
    active: false
  OptionalWhenBraces:
    active: false
  PreferToOverPairSyntax:
    active: false
  ProtectedMemberInFinalClass:
    active: false
  RedundantVisibilityModifierRule:
    active: false
  ReturnCount:
    active: true
    max: 2
    excludedFunctions: "equals"
    excludeLabeled: false
    excludeReturnFromLambda: true
  SafeCast:
    active: true
  SerialVersionUIDInSerializableClass:
    active: false
  SpacingBetweenPackageAndImports:
    active: false
  ThrowsCount:
    active: true
    max: 2
  TrailingWhitespace:
    active: false
  UnderscoresInNumericLiterals:
    active: false
    acceptableDecimalLength: 5
  UnnecessaryAbstractClass:
    active: false
    excludeAnnotatedClasses: "dagger.Module"
  UnnecessaryApply:
    active: false
  UnnecessaryInheritance:
    active: false
  UnnecessaryLet:
    active: false
  UnnecessaryParentheses:
    active: false
  UntilInsteadOfRangeTo:
    active: false
  UnusedImports:
    active: false
  UnusedPrivateClass:
    active: false
  UnusedPrivateMember:
    active: false
    allowedNames: "(_|ignored|expected|serialVersionUID)"
  UseDataClass:
    active: false
    excludeAnnotatedClasses: ""
  UtilityClassWithPublicConstructor:
    active: false
  VarCouldBeVal:
    active: false
  WildcardImport:
    active: true
    excludeImports: 'java.util.*,kotlinx.android.synthetic.*'
```

Although I setted some rules with the attribute `autoCorrect: true` the code is not reformatted when I execute

```
./gradlew detekt
```

The analysis report is created and the issues are shown, but no auto correction has been made.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With 1.0 RC15 `autoCorrect` needs to be enabled in the gradle properties:

```
detekt {
    toolVersion = "$detekt_version"
    input = files("src/main/java")
    filters = ".*/resources/.*,.*/build/.*"
    config = files("../detekt/detekt-config.yml")
    autoCorrect = true
    reports {
        xml {
            enabled = true
        }
        html {
            enabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

From https://detekt.github.io/detekt/changelog-rc.html#rc15

> Cli/Gradle Plugin: autoCorrect inside the yaml config was removed. Please use the --auto-correct cli flag or autoCorrect detekt extension
> property in the Gradle plugin.

Comment: Could you please update the detekt documentation. Its almost impossible to know about this change otherwise

Comment: @caladeve Still Auto-correction not working on Android project.